# Blade server processor

Tags: blade-server

I need to know that if I have a blade server with 4 quad core processors, then is it possible to use each processor individually in a way that to install 4 OS on the same server (without using visualizing technologies, VM, HyperV, OVM etc), assign one processor to each OS and boot all 4 OS at the same time.
Thanks.

Comment: This is probably silly... but what OS are you planning to use? That's a critical part of this question.

Comment: @ewwhite Linux................

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user clearly hasn't done their homework and lacks understanding of basic IT concepts such as ring zero.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do, but a generic answer is that a containerization technology will be the best way to provide the resource isolation you're looking for.

[LXC is a good option.](https://linuxcontainers.org)

[Docker](https://www.docker.com) may be another possible approach, depending on your final goal.

Answer (score 3):

No it isn't possible from what I understand as the bios on each blade can only boot a single OS at a time.

A blade is just a minified rack server.

You could probably use containers or paravirtualisation within a single OS to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

No, as far as I know [LPAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_partition) technology has not yet made it to X86 servers.

Depending on what you actually want to achieve you'll need a container or HyperVisor technology to provide the hardware isolation and the capabilities to run multiple OS's concurrently.